# Pseudo Terminal Setup Error when running iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I tried to execute my app in the iOS Simulator. The build succeeded, but I got an alert with an error message before running and the app did not execute:

> **Pseudo Terminal Setup Error**
>   ErrorCode: 1 Errno: 6

[image: "Pseudo Terminal Setup Error - ErrorCode: 1 Errno: 6" alert]

What is this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 62):

**Just restart Xcode and run your app again.**

A **pseudo terminal** is an emulated terminal which is controlled by a master application, in this case, Xcode. For some reason, it encountered an error while trying to run that emulated terminal.

A common problem that can cause this is that you tried to run an instance of an iOS application **too quickly** after stopping another instance.

Comment: Such an annoying problem. What can I do? I'm fast.

Comment: it doesnt help. it will repeat again.

Comment: I'm not using simulator, I use iPhone6 to test and it was working and trying to test my app after 5 minutes i got this error with error code: 7. I'm using Xcode 9.4 beta. any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

How to resolve the error:

1. Quit the simulator
2. Restart Xcode - (Make sure that you have saved /committed any changes you have made to your code)

Comment: Quitting the simulator is not necessary for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can't post comment, that is why I wrote here. To those for who this issue repeats even after restarting Xcode, remember to kill process at all, don't just close the project.

Comment: why can't you post comment?

Comment: @JDOaktown I don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: You can post a comment here but not on the main question?

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment" Yeap